# Angular : Filter object data to build a Highchart Widget with distinct elements attributes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I am loading **json** data from a webservice and i'm injecting the received data to my list component ,

*like the following :*

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import {HttpService} from '../http.service';

import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpService]
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  dataItems: any;
  nb = 0;
  private dataUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/list';  // URL to web api
  constructor(private dataServer: HttpService ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataServer.loadDataItems(this.dataUrl).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataItems = data;
        console.log(this.dataItems);
        for (let i = 0 ; i < this.dataItems.length ; i++) {
          // console.log(this.dataItems[i].g);
          if (this.dataItems[i].browser === 'Firefox') {
            this.nbFirefox++
          }
          if (this.dataItems[i].browser === 'Chrome') {
            this.nbChrome++
          }
        }
        console.log(this.nbFirefox);  //print the firefox occurences
        console.log(this.nbCHrome);  //print the chrome occurences

        ...

// HIGHCHART WIDGET TO BUILD : 

        Highcharts.chart('systemsChart', {
          chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
          },
          title: {
            text: this.nb
          },
          tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
          },
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
              },
              showInLegend: true
            }
          },
          series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
              name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
              y: 56.33
            }, {
              name: 'Chrome',
              y: 24.03,
              sliced: true,
              selected: true
            }, {
              name: 'Firefox',
              y: 10.38
            }, {
              name: 'Safari',
              y: 4.77
            }, {
              name: 'Opera',
              y: 0.91
            }, {
              name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
              y: 0.2
            }]
          }]
        });
      }
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see in my data , `this.dataItems.browser` refers to several navigators , which i won't list manually , i want to filter dynamically each browser occurence , and build my Highchart widget , there i'm used to add every dimension with its value

**the static manner (bad) :**

```
series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
              name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
              y: 56.33
            }, {
              name: 'Chrome',
              y: 24.03,
              sliced: true,
              selected: true
            }, {
              name: 'Firefox',
              y: 10.38
            }, {
              name: 'Safari',
              y: 4.77
            }, {
              name: 'Opera',
              y: 0.91
            }, {
              name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
              y: 0.2
            }]
          }]
```

my purpose is to **filter my data and build the chart dynmaically without enterning each browser type** , since i don't know the complete list

**Any ideas ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to build your list of of browsers dynamically from the response like this:

```
browsers: {[key:string]:number} = {};
this.dataServer.loadDataItems(this.dataUrl).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.dataItems = data;
    console.log(this.dataItems);
    this.dataItems.forEach(item => {
        if (this.browsers[item.browser]) {
           this.browsers[item.browser] += 1;
        } else {
           this.browsers[item.browser] = 1;
        }
    });
  }
});
```

You'll then have an object with the browser names as keys and the number of occurrences as the value. You can then iterate over the key, value pairs to build your data series for your chart.

Comment: this is great for filtering , but how to build the chart with the browsers object , i need to map it to the chart

Comment: iterate over the key value pairs like you can with any JS object. Just search iterate over object JS and you'll find hundreds of answers.